# On run GlassFish starts up but Java Server Faces web app doesn't deploy

Tags: jsf, glassfish

I have managed to get GlassFish to start-up, but the Java Server Faces web app doesn't deploy.

When it finally says the module has not been deployed, it references this line

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" 
forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Could it be a username or password issue?

Comment: So if you create a real new empty web app without jsf etc and put just single plain html page in there, it works?

Comment: I haven’t tried that. I have tried going to the port of local host that is the admin GUI for the GlassFish server I am running, and that seems to work.  I don’t know how to run a file using GlassFish. I was hoping NetBeans would take care of it for me.

Comment: You sort of imply it works then since you added the jsf-2.2 tag, implying jsf and specifically version 2.2 is part of the problem (indirectly also implying it works with 2.1). I suspect it has no relation to jsf whatsoever.

Comment: I’m sorry, I listened to your response and changed it to JSF not JSF-2.2.

Comment: The GlassFish server does run. Do you have any advice on how to find out why the JSF doesn’t deploy?

Comment: See my first comment... and in 99% of the cases with a deploy error there is in the logging an error and a stacktrace,(.

Comment: I’m just trying to run it on localhost, and the GlassFish server admin GUI works, but the web app doesn’t deploy.

Comment: I want NetBeans to deploy it for easy debugging.

Comment: Sorry for repeating myself, but please see my first and second c'omment.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  No need to be sorry.